# How do i implement a sqlite3 databse in my react js website

Tags: reactjs, database, sqlite

I am building a music app with react js and wanted to store music file in my sqlite3 database with filereader. I have been googling how to implement splite3 database but it only show for react native. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use SQLite in the browser...
instead of that, there are some other options like IndexedDB or localStorage.
but they are so limited to store song files:

- IndexedDB: dependent on client disk space and operating system
- localStoage: 5MB

**Suggest: use [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start) cloud storage.**

Answer (score 0):

As of late 2022, I believe you can use Sqlite WASM (web assembly) packaged with your application, as a browser local database. I found this post from Nov 2022, talking about official support for web assembly in Sqlite 3.40:
https://devclass.com/2022/11/17/sqlite-3-40-released-with-official-support-for-wasm-web-sql-reborn/

I am trying to get a working example with reactjs, but haven't yet got it. Meanwhile, if you are still looking for a solution for this question, you could start here:
https://sqlite.org/wasm/doc/trunk/demo-123.md